# d3.js - how to change x position of rect on time scale axis?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm drawing bar graphs on time scale x-axis.
For example,

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([minDate, maxDate])
    .range([0, width]);

chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", bar_graph.x())
    .attr("y", d.value)
    .attr("width", 10);
```

The **left** corner of the rect starts at the assigned x-point, but I want to assign the x-point to the **center** of the rect.

Since it's time scale, simple substraction x-5 (assuming the width is 10px) didn't work. I tried invert(), also checked svg reference, but fail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed in setting the x attribute, it appears the issue lies in the bar_graph.x() statement, try doing something like this:

```
.attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.dateVal)-barwidth/2;})
```

See a full implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot, your example looks perfect. But it didn't work for mine, I think the problem is the different time format. I use the default Date()format...

Comment: In the example, the initial data set uses an array of numbers for the date, but they do get converted to an default javascript date: `data[i].dateVal = new Date(data[i].DateParts[0],data[i].DateParts[1],data[i].DateParts[2]);` so perhaps it is another issue